# Cant find IConnectionIdFactory in my assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am trying to extend my `CreateConnectionId` function to add custom logic when creating ConnectionId's in signalR

```
public class MyConnectionFactory : IConnectionIdFactory
{
   public string CreateConnectionId(IRequest request){
      //Code Goes Here
   }
}
```

but `IConnectionIdFactory` will not be resolved in my intellisense because it cannot find it in my assembly.  I have the following References in my References folder:

SignalR, SignalR.Hosting.AspNet, SignalR.Ninject

Answer (score 2):

It was renamed in a recent version. The `IConnectionIdFactory` interface was renamed to `IConnectionIdGenerator`.

You can find the interface under the `SignalR`namespace.

Your code should look like this instead:

```
public class MyConnectionFactory : IConnectionIdGenerator
{
    public string GenerateConnectionId(IRequest request)
    {
        return "some generated ID";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking at some old samples somewhere? What version of SignalR are you referencing? I believe that's a rather old interface pre-dating the MessageBus rework that was done. I *believe* the interface you're looking for now is [`IIdGenerator`](https://github.com/drub0y/SignalR/blob/master/SignalR/MessageBus/IIdGenerator.cs).